# How to run bootstrap in localhost using grunt, http-server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, yeoman

I'm new to grunt, bower, yeoman, angularJS and http-server.

I created a sample angularJS web app using above tools and i'm running it on http-server with 'grunt serve'

Now i wanted to create a bootsrap project same as angularJS project. So i installed

```
npm install -g generator-bootstrap
```

and in my project folder

```
C:/workspace/bootstrap>yo bootstrap
```

I typed and it created me the bootstrap components like this

```
C:/workspace/bootstrap/bower_components/bootstrap
```

inside bootstrap folder all the components and bower files are present.

Now i want to run my bootstrap project using `grunt serve`like i do in angularJS project.

but i cannot run it. please help me and if i'm wrong at any place please guide.

Comment: Please show us the content of ```c:\workspace\bootstrap``` and explain what "I cannot run it" means.

Comment: Maybe you could use bootstrap cdn ? You can find it on the first page, "Getting Started"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yo bootstrap`

if you use above command, the contents of your workspace will have only `bower_components` folder that is the reason `Grunt serve` will not work.

Create a yeoman project using `yo angular`
and it will ask for `Do want to include bootstrap(y/n) :`
just press `Y` and u good to go :)

Comment: but here i don't want angular. I need to have standalone bootstrap app in the way the angular app works with yo angular.

Comment: Still you have lot of options for this like make use of `npm install generator-bootstrap-less` or `npm install -g yeoman-bootstrap`, i am sure either of the one will help you .